# Maven optimize build

Tags: java, maven, rcp

I'm currently building a Java library with plugins compiled against RCP & RAP target platforms. Pom.xml files are automatically generated from MANIFEST.MF files with version 0.0.0.

My project looks like a typical Maven project:

```
 - features/
   - project.feature.rap/
   - project.feature.rcp/
 - releng/
   - project.updatesite.rap/
   - project.updatesite.rcp/
 - plugins/
   - several rcp & rap plugins
```

The current build steps are the following and it takes some time:

```
 1. Set-version on all plugins / features / releng
 2. Build & install RCP stuff using RCP target platform
 3. Build & install RAP stuff using RAP target platform
 4. Deploy all plugins in a Nexus
```

The main step taking time is the dependency resolution which is done 4 times. **Can I optimize somehow?**

Comment: Do you have a multi module build which has a parent as root and all other projects are childs of that? Why do you need to set the version of alll things for each build ? Are you using things like `3.5.0-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: Also if you want to improve the build speed, you might want to deploy on a specific target directory, with the dependencies already present so that you provide them in the pom.xml in scope "provided", and thus take less time at compile time

Comment: This is a OSGi build which has no scope `provided` depending how to follow pom first or manifest first approach...

Comment: It's a multi-module build yes, using .qualifier versions transformed to -SNAPSHOT by Maven. I didn't know about the dependencies scope but I'll have a look at this thanks!